# Connecting to SSAS from outside of domain

Tags: ssas, excel-2010, pivot-table, cube

I'm trying to connect to SSAS from outisde the domain in Excel 2010. When I go through, it lists the cubes etc, but when you finally go to add the pivot table on the sheet, you get the error:

```
An error was encountered in the transport layer.
```

Now if you go and before that hit properties before clicking ok on import data, click on definition, and edit the connection string to contain your password, you connect successfully. (This is not a feasible option for me to tell our users to do)

Now if I try to log in normally using excel 2013, it works perfectly. The main difference I saw in the connection string between excel 2010 and excel 2013 is tha the Provider in 2010 is MSOLAP.4 and in 2013 it is: MSOLAP.5. I already tried changing the provider to that in 2010 and it didn't make any difference.

I'm hoping there is some kind of hotfix for this for excel 2010, or if there is something simple I can modify on the server to make it work. I already tried using the http pump msmdpump.dll, but then it shows an error that it could not load the connection dialog.

Thanks for the help!
Ethan

Other Info: SSAS is version 2008.